pycharm changes automatically turned from blue to white and cannot commit
when I edit my code, the name of the code changes from white to blue.  when I try to commit, it says "no changes detected". The file name changes automatically to white.
Thanks
I tried to reconnect git and github but it won't work

Not enough information. Are you sure you are working on a git repository? (Is there a .git directory?). Check history. Verify that the file you are looking are in repository (and not on a copy elsewhere). There can be a lot of errors, but it is difficult to know. Edit a file and check with an external editor. Check with git command line...

Thanks I figure it out it was casued by my local repository being broken.
